# Join a line ending with a backslash with the next line awk (from Famous awk one-liners explained)

Tags: bash, awk, sed

This exercise is from the [AWK one-liners explained blog post by Peteris Krumins](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-two/)

Essentially this line

```
 awk '/\\$/ { sub(/\\$/,""); getline t; print $0 t; next }; 1'
```

joins every line ending with backslash with the next line:

e.g. input

```
12345\
6789
523435\
00000
```

Output

```
123456789
52343500000
```

---

The blog post says: 
Unfortunately this one liner fails to join more than 2 lines (this is left as an exercise to the reader to come up with a one-liner that joins arbitrary number of lines that end with backslash :)).

So using the AWK one-liner above, and if you use an input file with 2 or more lines one after the other that has a backslash at the end (input2), gives an incorrect answer (output2)
e.g. input2

```
12345\
6789\
523435\
00000
```

Output 2 - INCORRECT

```
123456789\
52343500000
```

I think, according to the post, the output should instead be output3:

Output 3 - CORRECT

```
12345678952343500000
```

How can one solve this problem (input as input2 and getting output3)?

Comment: Do NOT do `awk '/\\$/ { sub(/\\$/,""); getline t; print $0 t; next }; 1'`, it's the wrong approach and can fail in various ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
awk '/\\$/ { printf "%s", substr($0, 1, length($0)-1); next } 1' <<'EOF'
12345\
6789\
523435\
00000
EOF
```

which yields

```
12345678952343500000
```

This demonstrates that *3* consecutive (or more) line continuations work fine, unlike with the command in the question.

Explanation of the command:

- `/\\$/` matches a `\` at the end (`$`) of a line, signaling line continuation.
- `substr($0, 1, length($0)-1)` removes that trailing `\` from the input line, `$0`.
- By using `printf "%s"`, the (modified) current line is printed without a trailing newline, which means that whatever print command comes next will directly append to it, effectively joining the current and the next line.
- `next` finishes processing of the current line.
- `1` is a common `awk` idiom that is shorthand for `{ print }`, i.e., for simply printing the input line (with a trailing `\n`).

---

As for **why the original command doesn't work**:

```
awk '/\\$/ { sub(/\\$/,""); getline t; print $0 t; next }; 1
```

- On encountering a line-continuation character (`\` at the end of the current line), `getline t` reads the *next* line from the file and prints it *as is* after the *current* line.
- `next` then finishes processing of both the current and - thanks to the `getline` call - the *next* line, so that the next script cycle processes the line *after* the *next* line (*2* lines from the current one).
- Therefore, since the line read via `getline` is blindly printed and not examined in any way, it is *skipped* with respect to line-continuation-character processing.

In general, as Ed Morton points out in a comment, **use of `getline` is rarely the right solution and can lead to subtle bugs** - see http://awk.info/?tip/getline.

Comment: What if the final line has a trailing backslash?

Comment: Thanks, although I'm still a little confused as to how the answer is stored from one iteration to another? Normally there should be something like lineSoFar=lineSoFar (concatenate to) modifiedCurrentLine?  (hope that makes sense).

Comment: awk arrays and strings start at index 1, not 0. `substr($0,0,...)` is only doing what you want because when `substr()` finds an invalid index like `0` as the 2nd arg it defaults to `1` instead. Use `substr($0,1,...)`.

Comment: @n0741337: If the last line ends in `\ `, it will get printed without a trailing `\n` (with the `\ ` removed). However, note that this is technically an invalid line continuation.

Comment: @SonicProtein: Please look at the 3rd bullet point in the explanation. To rephrase it: _nothing_ is stored across lines; instead, when a line that ends in `\ ` is encountered,  `printf` _without `\n`_ is used, which automatically makes the next output command append to the _same_ line of _output_.